# Is it legal to store an STL iterator inside a union?

Tags: c++, stl, unions

Does any C++ standard guarantee that STL iterators can be stored in a union? If so, which standard?

For example:

```
union MyUnion {
   std::vector<int>::iterator iter;
   size_t size;
};
```

The reason that I ask is that I'm porting someone else's code that stores `std::vector` and `std::map` iterators in unions, and MSVC2013 doesn't seem to like it. I'm getting error C2621: illegal union member; type ... has a copy constructor. I would like to determine whether this is a bug in the code, a bug in the MS STL implementation, or a bug in my compiler.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your compiler is out of date. From the C++03 standard,

> An object
>   of a class with a non-trivial constructor (12.1), a non-trivial copy constructor (12.8), a non-trivial destructor
>   (12.4), or a non-trivial copy assignment operator (13.5.3, 12.8) cannot be a member of a union, nor can an
>   array of such objects.

However, this restriction has been removed in C++11. Instead there is a note:

> [ *Note:* If any non-static data member of a union has a non-trivial default
>   constructor (12.1), copy constructor (12.8), move constructor (12.8), copy assignment operator (12.8), move
>   assignment operator (12.8), or destructor (12.4), the corresponding member function of the union must be
>   user-provided or it will be implicitly deleted (8.4.3) for the union. — *end note* ]

So it's saying that, sure, you can put something with a non-trivial copy constructor inside a union, but then the union will not be copyable unless you write a copy constructor for it yourself.

Comment: Where can one get a list of all standard drafts?

Comment: @templateboy http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81656/where-do-i-find-the-current-c-or-c-standard-documents

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Brian's answer I was able to research more about this topic.

The C++11 feature that is being used is called *unrestricted unions*. [In case you're interested, here is the working group proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2544.pdf).

According to [this page at MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx), MSVC 2013 and earlier do not support unrestricted unions.

[Visual Studio 2014 CTP does support unrestricted unions](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2014/06/03/visual-studio-14-ctp.aspx).